# Symfony ChoiceType с загрузкой в него Entity из базы с помощью Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

Задача: форма регистрации, кроме всего прочего есть три выпадающих списка. В первом выбирается страна, после этого во второй Ajax'ом загружаются регионы и, при выборе региона, в третий грузятся города. Все три поля грузят данные из трёх моделей: Country, Region, City.

Код `buildForm`:

```
$builder
            ->add('country', EntityType::class, ['class' => 'AppBundle:Country',
                'choice_label' => 'name', 'placeholder' => '--- Выберите страну ---'])
            ->add('region', RegionSelectorType::class, [
                'required' => false])
            ->add('city', EntityType::class, ['class' => 'AppBundle:City', 'choice_label' => 'name', 'placeholder' => '--- Выберите город ---', 'required' => false])
            ->add('post_code', null, ['required' => false])
            ->add('address', null, ['required' => false])
```

Страна грузится сразу из сущности, их там немного. А вот для регионов и городов я хотел сделать динамическую загрузку, чтобы не грузить зря кучу данных.

Пока застопорился на регионе, город будет по тому же принципу. Проблема в том, что при отправке формы не происходит трансформация поля, по `ID`, в сущность. Пробовал и [Using Transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#using-the-transformer), [Creating a Reusable issue_selector Field](https://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#creating-a-reusable-issue-selector-field), в профилере пишется

> Unable to reverse value for property path "region": The choice "15"
>   does not exist or is not unique

Код моего типа `RegionSelectorType`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\RegionToNumberTransformer;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RegionSelectorType extends AbstractType
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new RegionToNumberTransformer($this->manager);
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'invalid_message' => 'Выбранный регион не существует',
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
}
```

Код трансформера:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use AppBundle\Entity\Region;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class RegionToNumberTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (region) to a string (number).
     *
     * @param  Region|null $region
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($region)
    {
        if (null === $region) {
            return '';
        }

        return $region->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string (number) to an object (region).
     *
     * @param  string $regionNumber
     * @return Region|null
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (region) is not found.
     */
    public function reverseTransform($regionNumber)
    {
        // no region number? It's optional, so that's ok
        if (!$regionNumber) {
            return;
        }

        $region = $this->manager
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Region')
            // query for the issue with this id
            ->find($regionNumber)
        ;

        if (null === $region) {
            // causes a validation error
            // this message is not shown to the user
            // see the invalid_message option
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'An region with number "%s" does not exist!',
                $regionNumber
            ));
        }

        return $region;
    }
}
```

Сервис регистрируется так:

```
services:
    app.form.type.region_selector:
        class: AppBundle\Form\RegionSelectorType
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: region_selector }
```

В общем, все по мануалу. Функция `reverseTransform()` трансформера вообще не срабатывает. Стоит только заменить в `getParent()` `ChoiceType::class` на `TextType::class`, как в примере все работает: `reverseTransform()` срабатывает, сущность создается. С `EntityType` вместо моего типа тоже все работает. Создаю регион типа `EntityType`, в `choices` подсовываю пустой массив, - ошибка. Т.е., в поле формы должен присутствовать `EntityType` тот, что потом будет возвращен сабмитом.

Первое что приходит в голову, создавать `EventListеner`, отлавливать передаваемое `ChoiceType`'ом значение и создавать на лету сущность, но зачем тогда `DataTransformer`'ы?

Symfony использую 3, но, думаю, на второй будут примерно те же проблемы и решение.

Comment: в Symfony2 были проблемы с тем, что нельзя просто так взять и использова choiceType для объектов без костылей. Вы пробовали возвратить из getParent EntityType::class? может быть это не будет решением вашей проблемы, но если заработает форма, это уже будет небольшое продвижение

Answer (score 1):

> но зачем тогда DataTransformer'ы?

`DataTransformer`ы тут ни при чём.

> Первое что приходит в голову, создавать EventListеner

Как вы сами верно заметили, можно создавать `EventListеner`. Но не обязательно использовать `ChoiceType`, можно использовать также `EntityType`.

Ниже примеры кода:

Форма регистрации:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\City;
use AppBundle\Entity\Country;
use AppBundle\Entity\Region;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class RegistrationForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder
            ->add('country', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Country::class,
            ])
            ->add('region', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Region::class,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)
                {
                    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                        ->where('r.country IS NULL')
                    ;
                    return $qb;
                },
            ])
            ->add('city', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => City::class,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)
                {
                    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                             ->where('c.region IS NULL')
                    ;
                    return $qb;
                },
            ])
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event)
        {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            /** @var $country Country */
            $country = $data['country'];
            $country = $country ? $country->getId() : false;

            /** @var $region Region */
            $region = $data['region'];
            $region = $region ? $region->getId() : false;

            $this->modifyForm($form, $country, $region);
        });

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event)
        {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            /** @var $country integer */
            $country = (int)$data['country'];
            $region = (int)$data['region'];

            $this->modifyForm($form, $country, $region);
        });
    }

    protected function modifyForm(FormInterface $form, $country, $region = null)
    {
        if ( $country )
        {
            $form->add('region', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Region::class,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ( $country )
                {
                    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                        ->where('r.country = :country')
                        ->setParameter('country', $country)
                        ->orderBy('r.name')
                    ;
                    return $qb;
                }
            ]);

            if ( $region )
            {
                $form->add('city', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => City::class,
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ( $region )
                    {
                        $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                            ->where('c.region = :region')
                            ->setParameter('region', $region)
                            ->orderBy('r.name')
                        ;
                        return $qb;
                    }
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

По умолчанию, регионы и города будут пустые, добились этого посредством параметра `quiery_builder`.

Если указана страна, то мы ловим это в `eventListener`, и меняем `query_builder`, чтобы получить регионы этой страны. Для городов тоже самое.

Думаю, с остальными справитесь.